# PostScript printer and JBIG2 scanner: consumer-level all-in-one / MFP recommendation

Tags: scanner, printer

For a few years now I have been looking for a consumer-level networked multifunction / all-in-one printer that has:

1. PostScript printing (not emulation);
2. Duplex printing;
3. A scanner that saves monochrome / bi-level images as JBIG2-compressed PDFs; **and**
4. A scan-to-email function (send scanned documents to email)

The only products I have seen that check all of these boxes are a few high-end business machines that cost $7K+.

It's 2016 and to me it seems I am not asking for much. Please correct me if I am wrong. Does a consumer-level MFP/all-in-one like this exist, and if it doesn't, do you think it will in the future?

*P.S. I am aware of the Xerox story with JBIG2 compression and number substitution; I am not sure whether that has sunk JBIG2's boat. If that did, it would be unfair, because JBIG2 is great for lossless monochrome compression.*